# Selected CoreData record between sessions in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

My CoreData is made up of company and employee - where 1 company can have many employees.

I allow the user to select a company and my app displays the employees - I want this company selection to be passed between sessions. Is it best to store this selection in UserDefaults, in the CoreData or some other way? What should I be storing, the UUID of the company, an entire entity, etc.? Or am I going about this all in the wrong way?

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
@SceneStorage("ListView.selectedItem") private var selectedItemId: String?
```

You use `SceneStorage` when you need automatic state restoration of the value. `SceneStorage` works very similar to `State`, except its initial value is restored by the system if it was previously saved, and the value is· shared with other `SceneStorage` variables in the same scene.
The system manages the saving and restoring of `SceneStorage` on your behalf. The underlying data that backs `SceneStorage` is not available to you, so you must access it via the `SceneStorage` property wrapper. The system makes no guarantees as to when and how often the data will be persisted.   -[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenestorage)

Put it anywhere the user makes a selection.

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)"),
    tag: item.objectID.description,
    selection: $selectedItemId,
    label: {Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")})
```